# in CKEditor, how can I turn 2 spaces into 1 after a period

Tags: ckeditor, spaces

Many people still type two spaces after a period.

CKeditor allows this (where as straight html will ignore the second). CKEditor adds `&nbsp;`.

I just want the one space without the `&nbsp;`.

Answer (score 0):

The best fix depends a little on your needs. What I do is I actually completely remove all entities which coincidentally gets rid of that problem as well. I do this by adding the following into my CKEditor `config.js` file

```
config.removePlugins = 'entities'; // replaces ä with &auml; and I don't want that
```

Another option would be to post-process the incoming data in your backend before saving. The way that would be done depends on what language you are using, but a simple string replace would suffice.